# Issue with Word VBA - Regex in VBA not working as expected

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to highlight certain patterns in Word document via VBA only! like 123-456-789 should be bold and red in color.
I managed to do it as well, but while I was checking the test cases, I made a weird observation:

```
Case 1: working perfectly fine includes:
Alex phone is 111-222-333
Alex second phone is 123-456-789
```

When I checked using my code both the `111-222-333` and `123-456-789` turned bold and red in color

But, the problem is happening with the scenario when same number is encountered again; At this point VBA is not able to highlight the second instance of the same number.

```
Case 2: not working includes:
Alex phone is 111-222-333
Alex second phone is also 111-222-333
```

The expected behavior here was `111-222-333` should be highlighted in both the lines. But to my surprise, only line 1's `111-222-333` is getting bold and turning red!

This is the code snippet I am using for this:

```
Public Sub mySub()

Dim count As Long
Dim extract As Variant
Dim matches As Variant
Dim match As Variant
Dim regex As VBScript_RegExp_55.regexp

extract = Array()
Set regex = New VBScript_RegExp_55.regexp

With regex
  .IgnoreCase =  True
  .MultiLine = True
  .Global = True
  .pattern = "\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3}\b"
End With

Set matches = regex.Execute(ActiveDocument.Range.text)
For Each match In matches
    Set wrdrng = wrdoc.Content
    Set wrdfind = wrdrng.Find
    
    With wrdfind
        .text = CStr(match.Value)
    End With

    If wrdrng.Execute = True Then
       wrdrng.Bold = True
       wrdrng.Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Note:
`ActiveDocument.Range.text` refers to the Word document which contains my 'Case 1' and 'Case 2' statements mentioned above. I want to make sure that even in 'Case 2', both the lines containing 111-222-333 should turn bold and red.

Comment: No need for Regex, this can be done using Word's Find function. If you don't know how to use wildcards with Word's Find see https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your code does not work as expected is because it is searching the entire document (i.e. starting at the beginning) in each iteration of your `For Each Match` loop.

In the case where the two phone numbers are different, that works, because the two match.Value strings are different. But when they are the same, Word only finds the first number and never the second number.

There are some other problems with the code as it stands (in fact it can't really work as it stands unless you have made some assignments to global/module level variables before calling this routine).

But first I'm wondering why you are using the `VBScript_RegExp_55.regexp` object when you could use Word's Find object instead. Is it because you *eventually* want to use `VBScript_RegExp_55.regexp` (maybe you know that WOrd's FInd with wildcards can't do what you eventually want to do? Because if you *can* use Word's Find, with or without wildcards, it's a lot simpler than trying to match VBScript regex matches with Ranges in a Word document. I would suggest you have a look around for examples of how to use it and perhaps [this article on Word Find](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm)

That said, I *think* in this case you can make your existing code work with your existing test cases by moving a couple of statements out of the Match loop. I've made a couple of other changes too. But I haven't thought about it any more than that:

```
Public Sub mysub()

' You don't currently use this
' Dim count As Long

' You don't use this
' Dim extract As Variant

' Could be a good reason why you declared these as Variant
Dim matches As VBScript_RegExp_55.MatchCollection
Dim match As VBScript_RegExp_55.Match

Dim regex As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp

' I had to declare these - maybe you declared them at the Module level?
Dim wrdoc As Word.Document
Dim wrdrng As Word.Range
Dim wrdfind As Word.Find

' You don't use this
'extract = Array()
Set regex = New VBScript_RegExp_55.regexp

With regex
  .IgnoreCase = True
  .MultiLine = True
  .Global = True
  .Pattern = "\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3}\b"
End With

' Maybe you did this somewhere else
Set wrdoc = ActiveDocument

' I moved these two statements outside the loop
Set wrdrng = wrdoc.Content
Set wrdfind = wrdrng.Find

Set matches = regex.Execute(ActiveDocument.Range.Text)
' or, possibly
' Set matches = regex.Execute(wrdrng.Text)

For Each match In matches
  
  With wrdfind
    .Text = CStr(match.Value)
  End With

  If wrdfind.Execute = True Then
    wrdrng.Bold = True
    wrdrng.Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
    wrdrng.Start = wrdrng.End
    wrdrng.End = wrdoc.Content.End
  End If
Next

' Ideally destroy objects you created  
Set wrdfind = Nothing
Set wrdrng = Nothing
Set wrdoc = Nothing
Set regex = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: That above sub worked for Case 2.! But, its failing Case 1 now.! :/ Please have a look

Comment: @Annu that's why I was trying to steer you towards using Word's own feature, because I do not particularly want to put effort into making the existing code work if you can do what you need using Word's built-in feature. I think you should do what I and someone else have suggested and take a look. That said, I've made a small change that may fix it for you (two lines added after you set the color to wdRed). It may need some further tweaking to deal with "edge cases" e.g. at end of document but now you've got the general idea you should be able to deal with that.